# What about a "year's race" as a new reputation league?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-leagues

As someone who is rather new on SO, but nevertheless very active, it is great fun to collect rep points. If not to say I'm rather addicted :-)

As discussed in many other contributions, users with a long SO history are far away and some of them still increasing their ranks due to very old contributions, which create rep points for years...

No fear, I do not want to discuss this point again :-)

So my suggestion: Let's open a new "league" (I'd call it "Year's race" similar to the ATP system in Tennis) where only rep points are taken into account, where the original action happened not more than one year ago.

This would be very motivating - at least for me.

#### EDIT

There are 6 down votes already but no comment why... Is this just *protecting the establishment* or is there any reason against?

Comment: You're in luck. http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow

Comment: @approxiblue Hihi, no, that's not the thing l'm talking about ... If someone stopped contributing two years ago he would still get rep points due to his ancient answers

Comment: Just FYI, the establishment doesn't care about reputation anymore. The novelty has completely worn off by the time you've garnered a few thousand points. People are probably downvoting this because they see it as a pointless addition to a site that is already over-gamified, to the point where it sometimes interferes with our primary mission.

Comment: @CodyGray I do understand this (and have to accept it of course). Being on SO for years is a value on its own... Well, in some years I'll react the same if a newb then places the same suggestion probably... :-)

Comment: seems kinda unfair that I wouldn't be able to get the full rep cap worth of rep counting toward that league just because i get incidental upvotes every day. just like it's unfair that i get incidental upvotes that count toward that league. Really no good solution that doesn't affect one party or the other.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow is gamified enough as-is.

Regarding this specific proposal, I think the primary effect of a leaderboard for recent contributions would be to encourage answering obvious duplicate questions instead of closing them.

Comment: Fair point... One could exclude points from questions closed as duplicates...